# Word order when using the "Präteritum" of a modal verb (können) with the "Präsens" of another verb (haben) in a subordinating conjunction?

Tags: word-order, verb-usage, modal-verb, subordinate-clause, preterite

I am trying to write "..., so that he could have a car and other niceties" and I have it translated to "..., damit er ein Auto und andere Annehmlichkeiten haben konnte."

I am getting tripped up with word order because of the combination of the "Präteritum" form of "*können*" and the "Präsens" of "*haben*" in a subordinate clause.

Comment: niceties? This is the first time I've heard this word

Comment: I wonder what tense this is 

Answer (score 3):

In a main clause the modal verb is finite and is put in second position: *Er konnte ein Auto und andere Annehmlichkeiten haben.* Everything is the same in a subordinate clause except that the finite verb is placed at the end: *... damit er ein Auto und andere Annehmlichkeiten haben konnte.* Part of your premise is wrong; *haben* is in the infinitive, and so is not present, past, or any other tense.